# GData API and cross-domain ajax calls

Tags: ajax, jquery, gdata-api

I want to get xml data from google server using it's API. so, i can't make any changes to response. So, How do I make this call that work for me:

```
 $.ajax({  
     type: 'POST',  
     url: 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin',  
     contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',  
     data: { accountType : "HOSTED", Email : ""+Adminemail+"", Passwd : ""+adminpass+"", service : "cp"}, // cp for contact service..
    success: function (response) {
alert(response); });
```

I want make some GET, PUT, DELETE call as well so, I don't want to use any function like $.getJSON();I want to make it possible through $.ajax() only.

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way. I don't even think there's a hard way.

Comment: Then what do you think how do I overcome this situation?

Comment: Go for a server side solution. See my answer. What server software do you use?

Comment: worst thing is that I am not using any server side scripting language in this project.!

Comment: Then you got a problem. Normal browsers won't allow you to do this.

Comment: If you [use the official GData API instead of brewing your own, this is supported](http://code.google.com/intl/sv/apis/gdata/docs/auth/overview.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think only way to do this is use of server side scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers won't allow [cross site scripting](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). (An ajax call that is not in your own domain).

So if you want to call such an url (https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin), do it server side.

Answer (score 1):

Cross domain posting is blocked by the browser. You could write your own browser. Since this is probably not an option, you could post to your own server and from there post to the other server. I think you can post data to another server using cUrl if you're using PHP.

There's a nice example [here](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/sending-post-form-data-with-php-curl.html).

Answer (score 1):

The third party must provide a [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) api.